# Application Error shows up on publishing on Heroku

Tags: angular, rest, api, mean

I've successfully run MEAN app on `localhost:5000` using `heroku local web` and it works fine. Using cloud deployment, it does work and **Application Error** message appears.

```
server.js:

> `var express=require('express');
var path= require('path');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');`enter code here`
var cors=require('cors');

var tasks=require('./routes/tasks');

var app=express();

var port=process.env.port || 3000;

app.use(cors());

//Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//Body parser middle-ware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use('/api',tasks);
app.use('/**',(request,response,next)=>{
    response.status(404);
    response.send('Not Found');
    //response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/Notfound/notfound.html');
});


app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('The server is running on port ' + port);
});

----------------------
here is  routes/tasks.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/',(request,response,next)=>{
    response.send('Index Page');
});

module.exports=router;

===============================================================
opening from local redirects me to http://localhost:5000/tasks  as per routes/tasks.js 
but the cloud version does not work, I tried to read the console but in vain

Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

When I replaced `port` with `PORT` , it ran ok with Heroku but locally it is still Ok to just leave it as it is `port`